# How to create and use a class level fileStream object?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to declare a class level fileStream object but initialize it within specific methods and then close it... this could happen repeatedly. I don't know the correct terminology to really describe what I am trying to do, so here is some psuedo-ish code that should show you want I am trying to do.

```
    Some Class () {

      declare empty filestream object named FILEREADER

      Some Method () {

        intialize FILEREADER with text_file.txt

        DO STUFF

        FILEREADER.Close();
      }

      Some Method Two () {

        intialize FILEREADER with text_file.txt

        DO STUFF

        FILEREADER.Close();
      }
    }
```

Now I know how to declare and initialize this object at the same time, I just don't know how to break it into two steps. The following is the single step equivalent of what I am trying to do.

```
    FileStream FILEREADER = new FileStream("text_file.txt",
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: `FILEREADER = null;`?

Comment: If you're closing it every time, what's the benefit in having it declared at the class level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    FileStream FILEREADER; // will be null by default

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (FILEREADER = new FileStream(
            "text_file.txt",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        FILEREADER = null;
    }
    void SomeMethod2()
    {
        using (FILEREADER = new FileStream(
            "text_file.txt",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        FILEREADER = null;
    }
}
```

Although I'm not really sure why you need to have `FILEREADER` as a member. Why not just declare a local `FileStream` in each of your methods? If you open and close it in each method, then there's no need in storing it outside of those methods.

You really should just do this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (FileStream FILEREADER = new FileStream(
            "text_file.txt",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    void SomeMethod2()
    {
        using (FileStream FILEREADER = new FileStream(
            "text_file.txt",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

(Note in all of this code that the `using` clauses will automatically dispose of and `Close` the `FileStream`.)

Comment: Ok I think this is closest to what I am thinking. Let me explain what my goal is, there maybe a completely different way of doing this. I have a text file that is read from in some methods and written to in others, it is technically possible for a situation to occur where the file is read while the other method isn't done writing to it. If this were to happen then the information that is read would be incomplete and this would cause all sorts of bad stuff to happen.

With it declared at the class level I can lock the object when it is being used.

Comment: @JoW. Ok, then just use the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't want to copypaste the `new FileStream(...)` code with those specific parameters to each method? Then create a method that does that:

```
public class DoesStuffToFiles 
{
    private FileStream OpenTextFile()
    {
        return new FileStream("text_file.txt",
                              FileMode.Open, 
                              FileAccess.Read, 
                              FileShare.ReadWrite);
    }

    public void SomeMethod1()
    {
        using (var file = OpenTextFile())
        {

        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod2()
    {
        using (var file = OpenTextFile())
        {

        }
    }
}
```